# revert git merge which doesn't have a single merge commit

Tags: git

I used git to merge changes from one branch into another.
For some reason I didn't get a merge commit and I am 30 commits ahead of my remote branch...

```
* branch_I_merged_into        5222g3555b33 [origin/remote_branch: ahead 30]
```

branch 'branch_I_merged_into' was only three commits ahead of branch 'origin/remote_branch' before I did the merge.

How can I view what commits where merged in? I really need to revert the 'merge' - i.e. 27 commits and I don't know how...

Is there some way I can track down which commits I merged in?

Thank You!

Comment: It sounds like you ran `git merge <commit-specifier>` and Git said: "fast forward" and moved your branch to point directly to the specified commit. If so, you can undo it by doing `git reset --hard <previous-commit>`. The ID of the previous commit will be in the reflog for the current branch (and the reflog for `HEAD`, too, but it will be clearer from the branch's reflog).

Comment: In the future if you want to force a merge-commit to be created even in the case of a fast-forward, you can add  --no-ff to your merge command.  It means no-fast-forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log current_branch..other_branch
```

this shows u the commits reachable by other_branch that current_branch doesn't have.  in other words, the additions.

and yeah i think u got a fast forward merge, it saw that the other branch has the tip of your branch as an ancestor and your head simply moved up